# Spider issue, link path is incorrect to spider but correct to browser

Tags: php, hyperlink, web-crawler

I have a table of links like this

```
<a href="dealerships/<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>">Acura</a>

<a href="/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>">GMC</a>

<a href="chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>">Maserati</a>
```

The first one shows up properly to the spider simulators I am using (two different ones). The second and third do not, but the first one resolves as:

```
http://www.grademydealer.com/dealerships/texas/dealerships/texas/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=texas (WRONG)
```

The other two are correct:

```
http://www.grademydealer.com/dealerships/texas/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=texas
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with the limited information I'm going to hazard a guess. I think the missing `/` is appending the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to the current page. So I'm guessing you are viewing this from the page dealerships/teax. Changing <a href="dealerships to <a href="/dealerships

will make 
http://www.grademydealer.com/dealerships/texas/dealerships/texas/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=texas

http://www.grademydealer.com/dealerships/texas/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=texas

Also, you need to sanitize the _GET variables. What's to stop the user putting malicious code into the the get and sending to a user?

I hope that helps.

Comment: Why is the OP able to see the PHP code when browsing? I assume that he/she will be served HTML only... it seems like there is a bug in the page the OP is crawling.

Comment: possibly, but he says the links are resolving the pasted hyperlinks, i don't think (although i may be wrong). I think the issue is that they are not pointing to the correct page, as he is not giving an absolute path. maybe the op can clirify?

Comment: You cant see the php in the html ;-)... the links are not pointing to the correct path like you said. It's strange.. I converted the entire table to absolute paths - http://grademydealer/dealerships/..... this works, i just didnt think i had to do that

Comment: you can just put a forward slash at the beggining of the href. if i'm on page www.test.com/test/test/?test=te and i put <a href="test">test</a> it would point to www.test.com/test/test/test but if i put a link to <a href="/test"> it would point to www.test.com/test i hope that helps.

Comment: sorry i pressed enter too soon. but basically if your on page  http://www.grademydealer.com/dealerships/texas?state=texas and link to <a href="dealerships/<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=<?php echo $_GET['state'];?> you will get  http://www.grademydealer.com/dealerships/texas/dealerships/texas/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=texas but if you link to <a href="/dealerships/<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>/chevrolet/?brand=chevrolet&state=<?php echo $_GET['state'];?>">Acura</a> you should get the desired result i hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're crawling a PHP page, however, to me it seems to be a badly built PHP page because the PHP code is appearing in the links (but I'm not a PHP programmer). Normally `<?php` donates the insertion of PHP code which after execution by the framework will result in an actual HTML, or whatever else is necessary to be served to the client. See [PHP syntax for more info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php).

Can you share the URL which you crawled in order to get the first link, which you claim can be resolved. I'd love to see the HTML code.

Comment: i am showing how the code is written, of course it renders with the appropriate text from the echo.

Comment: I have completed a fix by including the  full path http:// so the page is not rendering as above now. but i would still like to know why it is happening.

Comment: Daniel Hunter, its because if you dont specify a / at the beggining of the hyperlink it will add that to the current page ( without the querystring) read my reply above :)

Comment: @DanielHunter ah, ok that was the confusing part :): I thought you're actually getting PHP code embedded in your HTML. It appears that your crawler might not be handling relative paths correctly. Do you have access to the crawler code which is responsible for handling relative paths?

Comment: google is my main concern, but i am using this site http://www.webconfs.com/search-engine-spider-simulator.php and http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/spider/index.php

Comment: @DanielHunter I'm pretty sure that Google would know how to handle the relative paths. However, I would go the extra mile and avoid using relative paths period! It seems more convenient as a programmer, but causes all kinds of complications for the crawlers (as you've seen yourself). You can't be sure that a "less intelligent" crawler will be able to handle relative links correctly so be safe and serve the full URL. Perhaps use some sort of URL building tool to do so.